# A variable which suppose to be pygame.Surface appears like a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, pygame, typeerror

I just added a function to my code which should display an image from a directory. It requires an argument which specifies which window it displays it in. When I try to pass it in I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Pygame.py", line 122, in <module>
    Player.load()
  File "Pygame.py", line 74, in load
    screen.blit(self.path, (self.x, self.y))
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str
```

My code:

```
import pygame

#init the pygame and create a screen
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1080,720))
done = False

#colours
blue = (0,0,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
yellow = (255,255,0)

#path to the background
bg_path = "Racing.png"

#path to the car image
car_path = "car.png"

#starts the game clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#opening bg image
background_image = pygame.image.load(bg_path).convert()

#class for all of the objects on the screen
class shape():
    def __init__(self, place, x, y):
        self.place = place
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class rectangle(shape):
    def __init__(self, place, colour, x, y, length, width):
        super().__init__(place,x, y)
        self.colour = colour
        self.length = length
        self.width = width

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.colour, pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y,
                         self.length, self.width))

    def move_up(self):
        self.y = self.y - 10

    def move_down(self):
        self.y = self.y + 10

    def move_right(self):
        self.x = self.x + 10

    def move_left(self):
        self.x = self.x - 10

class player(shape):
    def __init__(self, place, x, y, length, width, path):
        super().__init__(place,x, y)

        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.path = path

    def load(self):
        screen.blit(self.path, (self.x, self.y))

Rectangle = rectangle(screen, yellow, 540, 660, 60, 60)
Player = player(screen, 540, 600, 60, 60, car_path)
Player.load()
```

This isn't all of the code but the rest isn't related to the problem (I think). Please tell me if more code is needed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Show what you *did* pass through, and walk that backward to the problem point.  Remove superfluous code; you've posted about 75 lines of code for a 10-line problem.

Comment: `car_path` is a string, so `path` is a string, too. You've to load the image `pygame.image.load(car_path)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`car_path` is set as a `string` here

```
car_path = "car.png"
```

But `blit()` requires a `pygame.Surface` object for the first argument which [`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) would give you, i.e.

```
car_path = pygame.image.load("car.png")
```

instead.

Comment: Ohhh, that makes sense! I assumed that the problem was in the screen not beign the right type.

Thanks alot!

Comment: @EugeneLevinson No problem, let me know if it works